# Как сделать выборку из базы данных?

Tags: php, mysql, datatable, ssp.class.php

Использую Bootstrap DataTable, у нее есть возможность подгружать данные из базы динамически.
Запрос к базе формируется классом ssp.class.php ( https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php )
вот таким кодом:

```
echo json_encode( SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns ) );
```

точнее с помощью этого кода уже все отдает в DataTable.

Весь код скрипта:

```
$table = 'users';
$primaryKey = 'id';


$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'id', 'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'login',  'dt' => 1 ),
    array( 
        //
    ),
    array( 
        //
    ),
    array(
        //
    )
);
 $sql_details = array(
    'user' => 'root',
    'pass' => '',
    'db'   => 'root',
    'host' => 'localhost'
);


require_once 'lib_ssp.php';

echo json_encode( SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns ) );
```

Каким образом сделать чтобы данные с базы данных приходили только для конкретного юзера? ( в sql: WHERE `id_user` = '1' )

Answer (score -1):

Разобрался. Может кому то пригодится:

```
echo json_encode( SSP::complex($_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, null, "id_user='1'" ) );
```